# Edit regex so there is still a match when a grouped item DOESN'T appear

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following regex

```
(OUT|IN) (?P<typ>\D+?)(?=.*\bd:(?P<dest>\d+)\b)(?=.*\bs:(?P<src>\d+)\b)
```

This allows me to match on the following string format, or variations thereof, and put the numbers following *s:* and *d:* terms into groups *src* and *dest*:

```
OUT MYTYPE s:12 d:3
```

I would like to edit my regex so it will still match if one or more of these terms aren't there. i.e.

```
OUT MYTYPE s:12
```

would still match, and the group *src* would still contain 12, there just wouldn't be a *dest* group.

I tried putting **?** at the end of the word boundaries but it's coming up with errors:

```
(?=.*\bs:(?P<src>\d+)\b)?
```

Test [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/ZrsUvs/3)

-----*edit*-----

An earlier version of this question included digits within the  group. as @Ashish_Ranjan correctly pointed out, this would need *[^\d\s]+* rather than *\D+*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're trying to do:

```
(OUT|IN) (?P<typ>\S+)\s+[s:]{0,}(?P<dest>\d*)\s*[d:]{0,}(?P<src>\d*)
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZrsUvs/5)

Comment: I also found this works: (OUT|IN) (?P<typ>\D+?) (?=(.*\bd:)?(?P<dest>\d+)?\b)(?=(.*\bs:)?(?P<src>\d+)?\b)

Comment: `\D+` should be `[^\d\s]+` if your type contains digits, as in the question it does.